# GWT compile error: Rebind result cannot be abstract

Tags: gwt, compiler-errors

When i try to compile GWT i receive an error that com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.util.impl.DOMUtilImpl cannot be abstract. How to solve this error?

I am using GWT 2.6.

```
Nov 24, 2014 3:29:42 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
Compiling module nl.slimbetalen.slimbetalen
   Validating units:
      Ignored 5 units with compilation errors in first pass.
Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
   [ERROR] Errors in 'com/allen_sauer/gwt/log/client/util/DOMUtil.java'
      [ERROR] Line 33: Rebind result 'com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.util.impl.DOMUtilImpl' cannot be abstract
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:186)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.writeObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:223)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$6.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCache.transferToStream(DiskCache.java:185)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.DiskCacheToken.writeObject(DiskCacheToken.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor30.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.CachedCompilationUnit.writeObject(CachedCompilationUnit.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.PersistentUnitCache$6.run(PersistentUnitCache.java:492)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gwt-dnd/iaUxsUw02KE

Answer (score 1):

It seem the problem is an combination of com.allen_sauer.gwt.log and gwt 2.6. 
When i switch to gwt 2.5.1 the problem disapear.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same error with IE10 on window 7. I was using GWT 2.7.0. I was able to resolve the error by adding gwt-log dependency in my maven file. 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.allen-sauer.gwt.log/gwt-log/3.3.0

So I would suggest using and adding the latest GWT logs in your classpath.

Comment: If you can't either upgrade gwt-logs or downgrade gwt, you can simply declare in your module:
    <replace-with class="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.util.impl.DOMUtilImplIE6">
        <when-type-is class="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.client.util.impl.DOMUtilImpl" />
        <any>
          <when-property-is name="user.agent" value="ie10" />
        </any>
    </replace-with>

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GWT-log? In this case you need an update, because GWT 2.6.0 does not have an ie6 permutation by default. (with GWT 2.7.0 the support will be removed)

You can try to add:

```
<extend-property name="user.agent" values="ie6" />
```

Maybe that will solve the problem.

Otherwise use the GWT logger API:

http://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=en&u=http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html&prev=search